# Flutter firebase messaging, ios application don't receive token

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured firebase messaging in flutter app. It use [firebase messaging plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging). I have configured according to "iOS Integration" section from readme. Firebase is inited in `main.dart`

```
void main() async {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
  _firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: processMessage,
      onLaunch: processLaunch,
      onResume: processResume);
  String token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
  print("fcm token is: $token");
  runApp(TestApp());
}

Future<dynamic> processMessage(Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
  print("received message:");
  print(map);
}

Future<dynamic> processLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
  print("processing launch");
  print(map);
}

Future<dynamic> processResume(Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
  print("processing resume");
  print(map);
}
```

The problem is app don't receive token. So I deploy application to physical device, application starts, but don't see any output related to fcm, and ui not shown. I see following logs in IDEA:

```
5.10.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: .
5.10.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
```

Where can be problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It started to work when I moved firebase code to `TestApp`, seems like `main.dart` is wrong place for fcm code. I placed it inside `initState`.

Comment: sorry.. what exactly do you mean by TestApp?

Comment: @Amir Aslam It is main widget

Answer (score 0):

As of October 11 2018, the `getToken` implementation is faulty (see issues [17699](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17699) and [20378](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20378)).

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/789) to fix it, but it's still pending.

For now, in order to avoid problems with `getToken`, I would suggest listening to `onTokenRefresh` (that's what I do).

I didn't test the code below, but it's just an example of how you would have to adapt your code.

```
String _token;

void main() async {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

  Stream<String> fcmStream = _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh;
  fcmStream.listen((token) {
    // saveToken(token);
    print("fcm token is: $token");
    _token = token;     
  });

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: processMessage,
      onLaunch: processLaunch,
      onResume: processResume);

  runApp(TestApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Feu, in my case it started to work when I moved firebase related code inside `TestApp`, `initState` method